# Angular2 dependency injection, service not being injected during class inheritance

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm using `angular2` with `Typescript`. I'm trying to create a `base class` that can be inherited by other classes and within the base class, a service is injected. So far I can not get the `ajaxService` `injected` correctly into the `base class` that is being `inherited` into the `user class`. Specifically when a user is instantiated, and then the `save()` method is called from the `user` instance, the following line in the `base class`: `return _this._ajaxService.send(options);` doesn't work since `_ajaxService` is undefined.

Here is a `user class` that extends the `base class`:

```
import {Base} from '../utils/base';

export class User extends Base {

  // properties
  id = null;
  email = null;
  password = null;
  first_name = null;
  last_name = null;

  constructor(source) {
    _super.CopyProperties(source, this);
  }
}
```

Here is the `base class`:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AjaxService} from './ajax.service';

@Component({
  providers: [AjaxService]
})

export class Base {

  constructor(private _ajaxService: AjaxService) { }

  // methods
  public static CopyProperties(source:any, target:any):void {
    for(var prop in source){
      if(target[prop] !== undefined){
          target[prop] = source[prop];
      }
      else {
          console.error("Cannot set undefined property: " + prop);
      }
    }
  }

  save(options) {
    const _this = this;
    return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      const className = _this.constructor.name
                            .toLowerCase() + 's';
      const options = {
        data: JSON.stringify(_this),
        url: className,
        action: _this.id ? 'PATCH' : 'POST';
      };

      debugger;
      return _this._ajaxService.send(options);
    });
  }
}
```

This works fine except that `AjaxService` is not being injected into the base class. I guess this makes sense since user is being instantiated not base.

So how can I use `AjaxService` in the `Base module` when when `Base module is being extended on another class?

I guess when I instantiate user, the constructor in the user class is called but the constructor in the base class that injects the service is not being called.

Here's the `AjaxService`:

```
   import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()

export class AjaxService {

  // methods
  send(options) {
    const endpoint = options.url || "";
    const action = options.action || "GET";
    const data = options.data || {};

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      debugger;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000' + endpoint,
        headers: {
          Authentication: "",
          Accept: "application/vnd.app.v1",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data: data,
        method: action
      })
      .done((response) => {
        debugger;
        return resolve(response);
      })
      .fail((err) => {
        debugger;
        return reject(err);
      });
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: As far as I know injectables (AjaxService)  need to be annotated with `@Injectable()` in TS.

Comment: where do you use the `User` class? is it a component? does it have a template?

Answer (score 9):

It's ok to inject services in the base, but you have to pass it in from the User class regardless. You can't inherit the actual instantiation of the service from the Base, so you have to pass it down to the Base from User. This is not a limitation of TypeScript, but rather a feature of how DI works in general.

Something like this:

```
class User extends Base
  constructor(service: AjaxService) {
        super(service);
  }
```

If the Base instantiated the service for you, you would not be able to affect the instantiation from User. This would negate a lot of the benefits of DI overall since you would lose control by delegating dependency control to a different component.

I understand that you might be trying to reduce code duplication by specifying this in the Base, but this goes against the principle of DI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to reduce code duplication but this is going to be a nightmare...

Answer (score 2):

Each class in Angular 2 that you want to inject you must annotate. If it is not component, you must annotate it with `@Injectable()` annotation. If you inject class that already inject other class, you must create provider for that.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Base} from './base';
@Injectable()
export class User extends Base {
}
```

I created Plunker for you, i hope that it will solve your problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/p4o6w9GjWZWGfzA6cv41?p=preview

( look at console output )

PS. Please use Observable instead of Promises

Comment: I think you only need @Injectable in the services that you want to inject into other components?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Also, you need to include Service in array of providers for component.